# How to debug Angularjs ng-route and Threejs crash/issues?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, three.js, webgl

I have a website that is using angularjs with the `ng-route` directive to let the user navigate between views. The application uses Three.js for canvas WebGL rendering. I have a problem where the application crashes repeatedly on Chrome for Android and on IE11.

I have a hard time finding the exact issue, so I cannot at the moment provide a small, reproducible error case. This is what I mainly need help with - where to look.

So far I have narrowed it down to the `ng-route` view switching in conjunction with repeatedly re-initializing threejs renderers and scenes. I believe I can reproduce the issue using IE11 which gives me error code `887a0005`, which just says `the gpu device instance has been suspended` so it is unlikely that I can trace my problem from there.

The `887a005` error occurs when setting the size of the `WebGlRenderer` when `Three.js` executes the following line (18317 in Three.js revision 71):

```
_gl.viewport( _viewportX, _viewportY, _viewportWidth, _viewportHeight );
```

The app will run fine if I do not navigate around for a large length of time, but when navigating it crashes on Chrome for Android after between 3 and 10 view-switches.

Where would I look for the cause? Is this perhaps a memory problem? How would I narrow that down?

For what it's worth I am not using angularjs to manage the lifecycle of the objects creating threejs views. Is that maybe the problem?

Thanks for any help, and let me know if the question does not suit stackoverflow or is too narrow/broad!

Comment: For debugging ng-route can set breakpoints inside the to `$routeChangeStart` `$routeChangeSuccess` `$routeChangeError` and, `$routeUpdate` events.

Comment: Hey @Dan, unsure if that would help in this case as I don't believe ngRoute is the issue. I think the root cause is some memory problem with recreating renderers, scenes or planes/meshes in Three.js. Thanks for the comment anyways :)

Comment: Hi @ErikLundgren I'm working with a huge angular application with threejs and the most of the problems were related to the context management after page composition or refresh. Are you trying to keep track of deleted canvas' contexts?

Comment: Hi @pietro909, that sounds like a good idea. I managed to solve this issue using another way, so I'll provide an answer for my way (which may not be suitable for other applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this using the following steps:

- I removed renderers associated with my individual elements
- I created a renderer that would be used for the whole app
- I created and populated scenes on application start, in an `angular.run` block once.
- I then used the appropriate scene and fed it to the renderer for a given view, appending `renderer.domElement` in my angular directive

This sped up the app considerable and made a huge impact in responsiveness when clicking links or using buttons.

Creating and populating scenes on `angular.run` is not really performance optimal but worked fine for our use case. If you decide this is too much initial work for your app, I suggest either only setting up scenes when needed (such as when navigating to a given view) and/or cleaning scenes up after you (I believe multiple scenes and render creations together caused the memory leaks and slowdowns I was experiencing.

P.S. I want to say thanks to @pietro909's suggestion to keep track of contexts (or renderers as they create those). I believe that may be a more "optimal" solutions for when you aren't able to create multiple scenes on application load.